# How to access app roles claim from a NodeJS Azure Function using App Service Authentication

Tags: node.js, azure-functions

I'm getting auth and id tokens using MSAL in a client app, then posting them to /.auth/login/aad to get the App Service Authentication token. I then call my function with that token in the X-ZUMO-AUTH header.

The roles claim is present in the MSAL auth and id tokens, but not in the App Service Authentication token. I haven't been able to locate the roles on the request or context parameters of the function - though it's a little tricky since it can't be tested locally.

Is it possible to access the roles so I can use them for authorization? I'm using the v4 preview if that makes a difference.